# MongoDB: Getting data from an json array if the values exist in a particular order

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo. A document in my collections looks like this.

```
{
  train_name: <Train1>
  train_number: <#>
  details: [
      {
        station_name: <station1>
        arrives: <time>
        departs: <time>
        distance_travelled: <distance>
        halt: <>
      }

     {
        station_name: <station2>
        arrives: <time>
        departs: <time>
        distance_travelled: <distance>
        halt: <>
      }

    {
        station_name: <station3>
        arrives: <time>
        departs: <time>
        distance_travelled: <distance>
        halt: <>
      }

   ]
```

I want to query this database to find available trains between two stations. That is, the user will provide a 'source' station and a 'destination station' and I need a query to return all the available trains between the 'source' and 'destination'

From this example document, I should get results as 'Train1' if the user provides:

1. source - "station1" 
   destination - "station2"
2. source - "station1" 
   destination - "station3"

and **'Train1' should not be return if user has provided:**

1. source - "station2" 
   destination - "station1"
2. source - "station3" 
   destination - "station1"

So in short, I want to query and fetch results only if the values are present in the json list in a specific order.

So far, I have this

```
cursor = db.trains.find({"detail.station_name": {"$all": [source, destination]}},
                                {"train_name": True, "train_no": True, "_id": False})
```

But its not respecting the order. Its giving me all the train names that have both 'source' and 'destination' irrespective of their order.

I hope I was clear with my question. I'm new to mongodb. So any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, You are missing train direction in your data. i.e. What is the differentiation between your first example (source:station1) and second example (destination: station1) ? You could add some information OR change [schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) in your documents to indicate direction.  Also your query is essentially asking "Find me all station name matching `station1` AND `station2`, returning only field `train_name` and `train_no`. "

Comment: sorry if there was any confusion in my question. In the above example document, 'station1' is where the journey 'starts' and 'station3' is where the journey 'ends' for 'Train1'.  So the data is the 'detail' list is already sorted in correct oder.  All I need is get this train name if it runs between 'station1' (could be any source station) and 'station3' (could be any destination station).  I'm not sure how I can change the document schema to indicated direction. Can you please elaborate on that a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> So the data is the 'detail' list is already sorted in correct oder.

If the `details` value is already in sorted correct order, you could query using:

```
db.trains.find( 
          {$and:[
            {"details.0.station_name":"station1"},         
            {"details.station_name":"station2"}
          ]}, 
          {"train_name":1, train_number:1, _id:0}
);
```

Where you're searching for 'Find all trains where the first station name is `station1` AND any other stations include `station2`'.

Having said the above, depending on your use case/application dealing with array index may not always be ideal. i.e. you don't always know the ordering number except the first one.

> i'm not sure how I can change the document schema to indicated direction.Can you please elaborate on that a bit

There are various [data modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) that you could do to leverage and optimise your frequently used query. As the domain expert, you are the best person to make this decision. 
However, below are alternative examples:

You could include a field for `sourceStation` and `destinationStation` to easily query the start/end stations :

```
{
    sourceStation: {
        id: 001,
        name: "station1"
    },
    destinationStation:{
        id: 010,
        name: "station3"
    },
    details: [
      { station_name: "station1",
        ... },
      { station_name: "station2",
        ... },
      { station_name: "station3",
        ...}
    ],
    train_name: "Train1", 
    train_no: 88,
    arrives: <time>, 
    departs: <time>, 
    distance_travelled: <distance>
}
```

Or you could break-off the journeys into separate documents for granularity of journeys:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    sourceStation: {
        id: 001,
        name: "station1"
    },
    destinationStation:{
        id: 009,
        name: "station2"
    },
    train_name: "Train1", 
    train_no: 88,
    arrives: "0900", 
    departs: "0910", 
    distance_travelled: "3kms"
}, 

{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    sourceStation: {
        id: 009,
        name: "station2"
    },
    destinationStation:{
        id: 010,
        name: "station3"
    },
    train_name: "Train1", 
    train_no: 88,
    arrives: "0930", 
    departs: "0940", 
    distance_travelled: "4kms"
}
```

See also [Data Model Examples and Patterns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/) for more inspirations.

> I'm new to mongodb. So any help will be appreciated.

I would recommend to enrol in a free online course at [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/). Especially the M101 developer courses which covers schema design and querying.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Wan.  I's looking into this query that you posted. db.trains.find( 
          {$and:[
            {"details.0.station_name":"station1"},         
            {"details.station_name":"station2"}
          ]}, 
          {"train_name":1, train_number:1, _id:0}
);  Here it assumes that the station1 has to be the first station, but that might not be case. I's looking for a query that will give me the train if runs between 'station1' and 'station2'. (here station1 and station2 don't necessarily have to be the starting and ending point, resp.)

Comment: The condition is that station 2 should come after station1.  Can you please help me out if should a query can be made, else I will look into other schema options as you have suggested.  Thanks.

Comment: The ideal solution is to re-design your schema models. You could of course attempt to use the deprecated `map-reduce` or `$where`, but you won't be using the proper concept of NoSQL schema flexibility and would punish performance. You could also use any of the [supported MongoDB drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/) to get array indexes.